# How do i get a PHP generated HTML <ul> list to apply a rule to only the first <li> item in that list?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, joomla3.5

The code to generate a list of most read articles on my Joomla website AND display their intro images is as follows:

```
<ul class="mostread<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">



    <?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
      <?php $images = json_decode($item->images); ?>
        <?php if( $images->image_intro ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item->title); ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
        <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="name">
                <?php echo $item->title; ?>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>


</ul>
```

Having little to no experience with PHP, what do i need to do to this code to make it display only the first item's image instead of for all of them?

Comment: Remove `foreach` loop?

Comment: It is probably easier to achieve the desired result via CSS (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hek-mat was close, but the OP was trying to stop the **image** on the other posts from displaying, **not the link and title**.

```
<?php
  // track if we've seen an image yet or not
  $seen_first = false;

  foreach ( $list as $item ) :
    $images = json_decode( $item->images );

    // OP only wants posts with image_intros
    if ( $images->image_intro ) :

      // OP only wants to see the first item's image
      if ( ! $seen_first ) :
        ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $item->title ); ?>" />
        <?php

        // don't show another image
        $seen_first = true;

      // end "if first not seen yet"
      endif;

      // show the article (for all)
      ?>
        <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
          <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="name"><?php echo $item->title; ?></span>
          </a>
        </li> 
      <?php

    // end "if image_intro"
    endif;
  endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much to you and @hek-mat this worked. I've literally wasted a whole day just trying to get this to work. Time to learn PHP i think.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

Set a variable `$first = true;` after displaying first item set it to `false`.

```
<ul class="mostread<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">

    <?php 
    $first = true;//initially set true
    foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
      <?php $images = json_decode($item->images); ?>
        if($first==true){ ?> //checks $first is true if true prints
        <?php if( $images->image_intro ) : ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item->title); ?>" />
        <?php endif;

    <li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
        <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
            <span itemprop="name">
                <?php echo $item->title; ?>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li> 

    <?php 
    }
    $first = false;//after printing first item set it false
    endforeach; ?>


</ul>
```

Comment: Close. This has had the effect of displaying all images but only the text from the first result, instead of all text and only the image from the first result.

Comment: That causes only the first image and text to appear.

Answer (score 0):

To display only first item image you have do it like below.

```
<?php 
$first = true;//initially set true
foreach ($list as $item) : 

        $images = json_decode($item->images); 

        if($first==true): 

            if( $images->image_intro ) : ?>

                <img src="<?php echo $images->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($item->title); ?>" />

        <?php

            endif;

        endif;

        $first = false;

        ?>

<li itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Article">
    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="name">
            <?php echo $item->title; ?>
        </span>
    </a>
</li> 


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modifying the PHP, it is probably easier to add some CSS to a custom CSS file like this:

```
ul.mostread img {display: none;}
ul.mostread img:first-of-type {display: block;}
```

so that only the first image is displayed.

See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120 for instructions on how to create a custom CSS file in Joomla.

A custom CSS file also has the advantage that it won't be overwitten by any future Joomla or template updates.